# Issues with responsive mobile menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make this work? I keep fiddling around with the codes but I get no luck. I'm trying to make a responsive mobile menu. I tried searching google and can't find any solution. Thanks

```
   <div class="sidenav" id="sidenav">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;                                      
             </a>
 <a href="#">Home</a>
 <a href="#">Order</a>
 <a href="#">About</a>
 </div>
 <div class="main_header">
    <div class="main_nav">
        <span onlick="openNav()">&#9776</span>
    </div>
     <h1>Treat your tastebuds</h1>
    <a href="#" class="btn_one">Order a coffee</a>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("main_nav").style.width = "100%";
     }
    function closeNav(){
        document.getElementById("closeNav").style.width="0";
    }
  </script>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.sidenav{
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: white;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition:0.5s;
}
sidenav a{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 100;
text-align: center; 
padding: 1em 0;
}
.main_header{
background-image: url(coffee1.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: left;
color: white;
width: 100%;
height: 750px;
}
.main_header h1{
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: 900;
margin-left: 2em;
margin-top: 8em;
}
.btn_one{
margin-left: 11em;
color: white;
background-color: darkslategray;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 1em 2.5em;
}
.main_nav{
height: 40px;
}
.main_nav span{
color: white;
font-size: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 40px;
margin-left: 0.25em;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the bootstrap framework is an option.

Here is an example that provides a side navigation.

https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/

Answer (score 0):

You have various typos in your code as well as undefined elements that you're attempting to manipulate.

Firstly, you have:`<span onlick="openNav()">&#9776</span>` which contains a typo. It's 'onclick', not 'onlick'.

Next, you're attempting to manipulate an element "main_nav", but in your HTML and CSS, you defined main_nav as a class (using a period). So, if you change your html to `<div class="main_nav">` your issue for that will be fixed.

I'm unsure what your final menu design will be, but those changes will fix the problems you're running into.